# RMI java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <class name> (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Tags: java, rmi, unmarshalling

I get this Exception when I call the service in my client code
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: serveur.InterfaceServices (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
The code is :

```
try
{
   InterfaceServices servi=(InterfaceServices) Naming.lookup ("rmi://127.0.0.1/serv");
   p=  servi.verif(data);
}
catch(Exception ee)
{
  System.out.println("RMI CLIENT PROBLEM +"+ ee.toString());
}
```

Comment: You need to forget about the 'with Netbeans' part. Unless you are just experimenting, your application is going to be deployed *without* Netbeans. And your question had nothing to do with policy files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RMI ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085064/rmi-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Solved: the server and the client application must have the same name of package "mypackage" for example.

Comment: They must be the *same class.* Not a copy of the same code in a different package, or with a different name, or ... In any case copying source code around when you could be copying the binary is a fool's errand.